# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I'm setting up a laravel project and see an error as below. I have no clue as to what the cause is. Please help identify a fix

```
ncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'styles')
    at Object.loader (D:\Projects\amazing-ads-tool\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\index.js:96:34)
    at ./resources/js/components/AmzSkuSearchComponent.vue (app.js?id=1015a1c7a0a1d02c4d096e84f60ab811:132:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=1015a1c7a0a1d02c4d096e84f60ab811:232:42)
    at webpackContext (app.js?id=1015a1c7a0a1d02c4d096e84f60ab811:182:9)
    at eval (app.js:20:75)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at eval (app.js:20:14)
    at ./resources/js/app.js (app.js?id=1015a1c7a0a1d02c4d096e84f60ab811:18:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=1015a1c7a0a1d02c4d096e84f60ab811:232:42)
    at app.js?id=1015a1c7a0a1d02c4d096e84f60ab811:385:64
    at __webpack_require__.O (app.js?id=1015a1c7a0a1d02c4d096e84f60ab811:269:23)
```

I followed several of the SO posts

Comment: somewhere in your code you may be trying to read `styles` property of an undefined value. The error trace may help you search your own code to find where you made the error - chances are you're trying to use some reactive value before it has been initialised

Comment: Oh, never mind, this is a build error not a run-time error ...